# Why is NOOBS not showing me all the operating systems?

Tags: noobs

A week or two ago I dropped NOOBS 2.3 on to a 32 GB SD card, booted it in my Raspberry Pi Zero W, configured the network, and was then presented with a nice long list of OSes that I could install, including RISC OS, a couple of different media player distributions, and a couple of different "game console" distributions, and more.

I have since tried again, with the following changes:

1. I've replaced the SD card with a much smaller one that has only a FAT partition with `bootcode.bin` on it. (This is the version from the [next branch](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/next/) since it's not clear to me if the master branch version will boot partitions from USB yet.)
2. I've installed NOOBS 2.4 (a newer version than I was previously using) on a 32 GB USB flash drive.

NOOBS boots up just fine, and I configure the network as I did before, but now I see far fewer operating systems in the list: just a media player distribution (I forget which one), Raspbian+PIXEL, Raspbian Lite, and the empty partition for exchanging data between OSes.

If I add `showall` (shows all available OSes regardless of your Raspberry Pi model) to the `recovery.cmdline` file and try again, I'm shown an additional version of the media player distribution (I think it added a "Pi2" version), but still nothing further.

What's gone wrong, and how do I get back all the other operating systems?

Comment: You don't say what you want to run. You would have to ask the Foundation why, but they have removed most of the options (some no longer worked) Try [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) This is a modified NOOBS without some of its limitations.

Comment: I want to run, amongst other things both the game emulator distros and RISC OS. I did try at least one of the game distros installed with NOOBS 2.3 and it seemed to work ok, albeit a bit slowly sometimes. Has the foundation announced this change and the reasoning behind it?